# Using multiple "count distinct" has huge performance impact

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

On Google Cloud Spanner we are running into a memory issue for some queries that analyse lot of data

```
GenerateArrayEvaluator ran out of memory during buffering one value 
(original error message 'GenerateArrayEvaluator ran out of memory. 
Requested: 9 byte(s). Already reserved: 294649856 byte(s). 
Limit: 294649856 byte(s). Details: Cannot reserve 9 bytes to create a new segment 
The operation HashJoinIterator is reserving the most memory (114717769 bytes).'). 
Requested: 0 byte(s). Already reserved: 294649856 byte(s). Limit: 294649856 byte(s).
Max Memory Operation: The operation HashJoinIterator is reserving the most memory (114717769 bytes).
```

I figured out that for some reasons the query is performing very unoptimized operations.
I was able to isolate the guilty part of the query. So this is the minimum query to reproduce this situation:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT a) a,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b) b
FROM foo
WHERE primary_split_key = "..."
```

That query has 2 clauses `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`, that's the issue. It will create a `map compute` operation that will multiply the number of rows returned by the number of `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` in the select clause.

In other words if `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE primary_split_key = "..."` returns 10 rows, then the map compute will generate 20 rows (`10row * 2countDistinct`).

If we have 500k rows and 3 `count distinct` then  it would generate 1.5million rows.

See the query explanation for 443k rows and 2 `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`:
[image: query explanation]

So we can say that this query scales really poorly.

We are working on tweaking it to get it to work better. However we would like to hear from Cloud Spanner team: is it the expected behavior of spanner/count distinct, or is it something you are willing to improve in the near future?

Also always happy to hear for alternatives from other user experiences.

EDIT:
I found some other cases of queries failing with the same error message. However those queries are explicitly using the function GENERATE_ARRAY that way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.id_a
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, a.some_number)) record
```

For that reason I suspect generate_array to be unoptimized or to have memory leak.

Comment: Since these needs a more attentive look and answer I would suggest you to open a support case (https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/) since it would get a bit more attention from the Spanner team than in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the memory issue, according to the error message, it appears that it is the `HashJoinIterator` that is consuming the most memory, the `GenerateArrayEvaluator` is simply a victim of the low memory situation caused by that. That also may to be the case with your second query.  Presumably, in your actual query you have a hash join that is trying to build a hash table on a large input ? Have you tried re-executing your query with a `join_method=apply_join` hint ?

The count distinct query you posted does indeed make as many passes over the data being aggregated as the number of distinct aggregates (2 in your case). While the 2s runtime shown in the plan is slower than I would expect, the runtime also depends on a number of other factors - your instance's CPU utilization and the degree of parallelism of your query so it is difficult to comment on that.

Comment: thanks for your answer off the top of my head apply_join was taking so long that it was not usable.

Comment: yes we are running it on large datasets. My guess is that the generate array method requires to spawn multiple instance of each rows in the memory. That's why I suspect it to be no optimized for use on large datasets. Unfortunately the spanner execution plan does not give us any hint about memory usage, making it hard to predict. We live in a situation where bigquery is too big for us and where cloud spanner shows its limitations. CPU usage and parallelism are fine (quite low actually) so they are not a factor is this equation. The memory issue happens everytimes, without any exception

Comment: Also, I want to add that I believe that the memory issue actually occurs before the hash join. I'm not very familiar with the execution plan, but I think it happens during the "map compute" opeation at the bottom of the stack - before the hash join execute

Comment: The `Cross Apply` in the plan will execute its map side for each row from the input side. The `GENERATE_ARRAY` will generate 2 copies of this row (for 2 distinct aggregates) , but these will be generated in a streaming manner. The only point where rows will be buffered is during the `Hash Aggregate` stage in your plan. If the parallelism of the query is low, then the `Hash Aggregate` step might run out of memory on a single node. You can experiment with the `use_additional_parallelism` hint to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I was not aware of this parallelism feature. The only doc I can find is here https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-syntax more docs about the implication is has on resource would be welcome, also how it scales with number of nodes as well as concrete use cases where it makes a diff.

Comment: If you'd like to answer the question about this hint, then you can answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334962/what-does-the-flag-use-additional-parallelism-do-is-spanner

Comment: Answered the question about the hint. My previous response is slightly incorrect in that the hint will not help much if the issue is out of memory, but can improve the latency of the query by prefetching the results of aggregation on remote nodes.