# What does the hint USE_ADDITIONAL_PARALLELISM do in Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

In the doc we can find a query hint named `USE_ADDITIONAL_PARALLELISM` here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-syntax#statement-hints

However the documentation is very short for it.

- From my understanding it will spread a single query to be executed on multiple nodes; is that correct?
- In what scenario would we use it?
- What is its impact on the infrastructure?
- How does it scale with number of nodes?
- Does it need a query that picks data from different splits, or does it work on a single split?

Any meaningful information about it is welcome.

PS: I was originally introduced to the hint in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60075381/using-multiple-count-distinct-has-huge-performance-impact/60329267?noredirect=1#comment106719622_60329267)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Spanner query may be executed on multiple remote servers.

[image: An illustration of the life of a query from the Cloud Spanner Query execution plans documentation]

Source: An [illustration of the life of a query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGwtU.png) from the Cloud Spanner "Query execution plans" documentation

The root node coordinates the query execution.

If the execution plan expects rows on multiple splits to satisfy the query predicate(s), multiple subplans are executed on the respective remote servers.

Due to the distributed nature of Spanner these subplans can sometimes be executed in parallel; for example, the right subplan execution is not dependent on the left subplan results.

If the `USE_ADDITIONAL_PARALLELISM` query hint is provided, the root node may choose to increase the number of parallel *remote executions*, if the execution plan includes multiple subplans.

To answer the original questions:

*From my understanding it will spread a single query to be executed on multiple nodes; is that correct?*

- This hint does not change how a query is executed, it only make it possible for subplans of that execution to be initiated with increased parallelism.

*In what scenario would we use it?*

- Especially in cases when a full table scale is required, this *may* lead to faster, *in wall-time*, query completion, but the trade offs concerning resource allocation, and the affects on other parallel operations, should also be considered.

*What is its impact on the infrastructure?*

- If an increased number of remote executions are run in parallel, the average CPU for the instance may increase.

*How does it scale with number of nodes?*

- An increased number of nodes provides additional capacity for parallel operations.

*Does it need a query that picks data from different splits, or does it work on a single split?*

- Benefits will likely be significantly higher for queries which require data that resides on multiple splits.

Comment: re: impact on infrastructure, would you be able to clarify whether a LOW_PRIORITY query that uses USE_ADDITIONAL_PARALLELISM has the potential to measurably impact latency of HIGH_PRIORITY queries? The documentation on this is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

A Cloud Spanner query may have multiple levels of distribution. The `USE_ADDITIONAL_PARALLELISM` query hint will cause a node executing a query to try and prefetch the results of subqueries further up in the distribution queue. This can be useful in scenarios such as queries doing full table scans or doing full table scans with aggregations like `COUNT()`, `MAX` , `MIN` etc. where identical subqueries can be distributed to many splits and where the individual subqueries to the splits return relatively little data (such as aggregation state). However, if the individual subqueries return significant data then using this hint can cause memory usage on the consuming node to go up significantly due to prefetching.